# App specific masterpage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, master-page, site

Is it possible to use a separate **masterpage** for each app?

Because I want to use a different masterpage for an **Wiki Library** which should use other settings as the default Pages on my Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that from SharePoint designer. Just change the master page in view pages ex. All Items.aspx, DisplayForm.aspx and so on.

```
MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"
```

In the top of the view pages, you will find above code. Now change `~masterurl/default.master` with your custom master page.

```
MasterPageFile="{Path}/{Master Page Name}.master"
```